Excel visual basic: Quiero dar click en una columna (título o encabezado) de un ListView por medio de CommandButton
Buen día. Se me ha presentado una necesidad de dar click a una columna (título o encabezado) de un ListView por medio de un CommandButton, pero no encuentro el código.
Así como al CommandButton se puede ejecutar esa acción por medio de éste código: CommandButton1.Value = True
Pero lo necesito para una columna del ListView.
Espero su ayuda. Gracias


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Me.ListView1.SortKey = 0 'Index de columna del ListView por la quieres ordenar, empieza por 0
Me.ListView1.SortOrder = VBA.IIf(Me.ListView1.SortOrder = lvwAscending, lvwDescending, lvwAscending) 'Permite alternar la ordenación
End Sub
